# WPF: Command on Canvas doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm implementing a simple `Tetris` game in `MVVM`. Main panel is `Canvas`. I want to navigate using keyboard arrows. To do that I have implemented `MoveLeftCommand` and `MoveRightCommand`. The commands are bound to the `ViewModel` inside `KeyBinding`.

Below my `xaml` implementation

```
<Canvas
    Width="{Binding Width}"
    Height="{Binding Height}"
    >
    <Canvas.InputBindings>
        <!-- One type of implementation -->
        <KeyBinding Key="{Binding MoveLeftCommand.GestureKey}"
                    Command="{Binding MoveRightCommand}"/>
        <!-- Different style of implementation -->
        <KeyBinding Key="{Binding MoveLeftCommand.GestureKey}"
                    Command="{Binding MoveLeftCommand}"/>
    </Canvas.InputBindings>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

The commands are initialized in the `ViewModel`'s constructor.

```
public RelayCommand MoveRightCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand MoveLeftCommand { get; set; }

public GamePanelViewModel()
{
    this.MoveLeftCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(MoveLeft));
    this.MoveLeftCommand.GestureKey = Key.Left;
    this.MoveRightCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(MoveRight));
    this.MoveRightCommand.GestureKey = Key.Right;
}
```

And here is command implementation:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action action;
    public Key GestureKey { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand(Action action) { this.action = action; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter) { this.action(); }
}
```

The soultion doesn't work.

In debug mode, when I press left or right arrow key the execution never even enters `CanExecute` method. It behaves as if it were unaware of the commands.

I've also tried forcing focus on the `Canvas`. No result.
Another thing I tried was to implement the commands differently. No result either.

However, when I've added a simple `Textbox` on top of the `Canvas`, and implemented the same commands on the `Textbox` it started to work - I could navigate the game using arrows.

Any idea why the commands on `Canvas` have been ignored?

Thanks

Comment: It's because `Canvas` does not have keyboard focus. WPF starts from focused control and goes up the visual tree to see if there's command that handles this gesture. For example put `Button` on your `Canvas` and make it focused then it should work or do something like `<Canvas ...  x:Name="myCanvas" Focusable="True">` and on `Window.Loaded` event do `myCanvas.Focus();`

Comment: Thanks, setting focus works perfectly. I tried forcing it before, but without setting `Focusable = True`. As to the first solution I figured out the trick with a different control but it was bit too hacky for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem arises from a simple issue of initialization .

The reason nothing works is because the binding took place before the RoutedCommand object was created.

replace your Command Properties with the following implementation :

```
    private RelayCommand moveRightCommand;
    public RelayCommand MoveRightCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (moveRightCommand == null)
            {
                moveRightCommand = new RelayCommand(MoveRight);
                moveRightCommand.GestureKey = Key.Right;
            }
            return moveRightCommand;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can create them the way you do , and raise a **PropertyChanged** event on the Command's property.

```
    private RelayCommand moveRightCommand;
    public RelayCommand MoveRightCommand
    {
        get
        {               
            return moveRightCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            moveRightCommand = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MoveRightCommand"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Commands are created in constructor before pointer to `GamePanelViewModel` is returned so it should work and will work if `Canvas`, or something in it, will have keyboard focus.

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions. Unfortunately neither worked.